# Does an asychronous web request in .Net help performance

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, webrequest

What is the performance difference, if any, between a regular request in C# .net and an asychronous one?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your use case. While there is no immediate performance benefit from using async in simple scenarios, it can be crucial in more complex ones, and for scalability.

For instance, sending multiple requests to many servers is obviously best done in parallel, this can be handled using async.

Regarding scalability, consider a web application that uses sync web requests to communicate with slow external servers. Since IIS only allocates a limited amount of threads to serve requests from users, when the number of users grow, there is a risk that all user threads will be blocked while waiting for the external web requests. This means that some user requests will be rejected by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, in asp.net you must use synchronous (until 4.5); but in a Windows Form or any other type of C# project though, it prevents the thread from being on hold.  Calling the ASYNC complete event, would allow you to update the proper information without putting the UI or the Main thread on hold.

Comment: You don't have to use synchronous web requests in ASP.NET.

Comment: Show me how using threads without using global variables prior to asp.net 4.5.  I would love to know how.

Comment: What does using global variables have to do with writing async code? ASP.NET has supported async handler and async pages since .NET 2.0. 4.5 does add some improvements (especially with await an async) but you *can* make async web requests in ASP.NET today.

Comment: @dfowler: I'd imagine you know what you're talking about, you're part of the .net team; totally awesome (also y'all rock).  I was always trained that we couldn't do that and I never got anything but compiler errors when trying to do async in asp.  Perhaps it was never important enough for me to make happen and hop through hoops.  I'd like to find out more though; twitAt-jamiebutd.

Answer (score 0):

under asychronous mode, The server can only reply what you want, this will minimize the network triffic, then minimize the response time, improve the user experience.

Comment: Why do you think synchronous processes make the server do something you don't want?

Comment: i have a batch i want to run in the background, that someone else coded and i want it to only run when my process count is low